# Reference for broader spectral lines?

Tags: spectra, infrared, resource-request

I'm looking for some reference listing spectral lines outside the visible spectrum.  (In particular, I'm looking for an element or compound that emits strongly in the 700-900nm range.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assuming your question is a reference request:**

I now about one resource that has a very broad range of spectral data, the

[NIST Atomic Spectra Database Lines Form](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/lines_form.html)

This has worked great for me.

[This page](http://www.lib.utexas.edu/chem/info/spectra.html) lists a couple of different alternatives. For the near IR case you are interested in, several collections are listed [here](https://sites.google.com/site/anthonycrastospectroscopy/ir-spectral-data).

Comment: even though it doesn't fit into your desired spectral range, I can also recommend the CDMS (cologne database for molecular spectroscopy) http://www.astro.uni-koeln.de/cdms/entries . As the name already says, it's rather useful for frequencies in the gigahertz regime

Comment: This may be the best answer: *Given a compound* I can now find the extended spectrum, but *given a spectral range* I'm not able to find a way to get a list of elements or compounds with relatively strong lines in that range.  But don't assume my physics is that strong: Is that question readily transformed into terms that will work with one of those data sources?

Answer (score 1):

Both potassium (766.5+769.9 nm) and sodium (818.3+819.4 nm) have strong resonance lines (doublets) in this part of the spectrum. There are also the calcium triplet lines at 849.8+854.2+866.2 nm.

These are the strongest atomic absorption lines seen in the spectra of solar-type stars or cooler at 700-900 nm.

A more specific answer would require the spectral type of the star.

To do something more general and/or extensive you would need to get hold of a good line list (a line list alone cannot easily tell you which lines will appear strongest in a stellar spectrum) and a spectral synthesis programme like SME or MOOG.